# Java - Ad headers to httpRequest's multipart files

Tags: java, http-headers, http-post

I'm searching for a good way to ad headers to an Http Request (Post Multipart) that takes a Json body and after that a few parts with files. The files are gonna be later mailed by a server and the idea is to pass an extra custom header only on the parts that contain the files to be presented inline.

Edit: IMPORTANT the requests are to be made from a java class.

So far I've managed to do it the old fashion way, writing directly to the OutputStream of an UrlHttpConnection (too complicated) and with HttpClient from Apache (better).

I was wondering if there's a better way or framework to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Http Request (Post Multipart), you can refer Java Spring Boot and Restful web services. for sample project you can refer Link :

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example-ajax-and-rest/

Comment: Requests are to be made from within a java class :)

Comment: I'll be looking into this too for frontend usage. Thanks :)